# mediawiki: How do you prevent rendering new line or line break in template?

Tags: line, newline, mediawiki, line-breaks

I am creating a complex template and I need new lines to break up the code so I can see it better. How do I break up a template without having it render new lines when the template is called?

Here's a snippet of code

{{#if: {{{value|}}}
    |'''Market value: '''{{{value}}}
}}

{{#if: {{{damage|}}} 
    |'''Damage: '''{{{damage}}}
}}

{{#if: {{{identified|}}} 
    |'''Description (sufficiently identified): '''"{{{identified}}}"
}}

{{#if: {{{unidentified|}}} 
    |'''Description (insufficiently identified): '''"{{{unidentified}}}"
}}

{{#if: {{{weight|}}} 
    |'''Weight: '''{{{weight}}} lb
}}

{{#if: {{{durability|}}} 
    |'''Durability: '''{{{durability}}}
}}

{{#if: {{{quality|}}} 
    |'''Quality rank: '''{{{quality}}}
}}

{{#if: {{{requirements|}}} 
    |'''Requirements: '''{{{requirements}}}
}}

{{#if: {{{materials|}}} 
    |'''Materials: '''{{{materials}}}
}}

{{#if: {{{materials|}}} 
    |'''Materials: '''{{{materials}}}
}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML style comments in MediaWiki templates:

```
}}<!--

-->{{#if: {{{durability|}}} |'''Durability: '''{{{durability}}}
}}<!--

-->{{#if: {{{quality|}}} |'''Quality rank: '''{{{quality}}}
}}<!--

-->
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but it's not really a solution as it is more work that it's worth. What I am going to do is simply code with notepad++ and before I copy/paste the code into wiki I will simply do a search/replace for \r\n

Comment: Just remember that removing all newlines will mess up you tables, if you have any. (Also: If it's a wiki, I guess the idea is that more people than you should be able to edit the content, and in that case I would highly recommend that you try and format the templates in a way that makes them more readable, even if requires some extra work.)

Comment: Ok, good advice. Just want to also say that I use <br> for my tables if I need to preserve new lines. Haven't had a problem yet. EDIT: I / our team is using a wiki like a game design doc, to store all info, attributes on items, ideas, etc. I am kinda like the team's wiki master.

Comment: ACTUALLY leo, I am now using your suggestion because I have to check my design every tiny change I make because I'm still a noob. So my method gets REALLY inconvenient. I just did an "extended (non regex)" search for }}\r\n{{ and replaced with }}<!--\r\n-->{{ and it's not ugly, it's not bad!